# Mongodb take only 10 firsts items of $$ROOT

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, nosql

I have a problem,
I do a group on my database and the problem is the $$ROOT can exceed the memory limit, so I would like to have the X first elements.

this is my group:

```
$group: {
        _id: {
          DOG_RACE: '$DOG_RACE',
          FOOD: '$FOOD'
        },
        total: {
          $count: {}
        },
        _raw: {
          $push: '$$ROOT'
        }
      }
```

the _raw contain all dogs grouped and there can be millions.

I tried to replace _raw: {} with an array with a slice but I got this error:

`The field '_raw' must be an accumulator object`

Can someone please have the syntaxe to do it ?
Thanks

EDIT

No this is what I'm trying:

```
$group: {
        _id: {
          DOG_RACE: '$DOG_RACE',
          FOOD: '$FOOD'
        },
        total: {
          $count: {}
        },
        _raw: {
          $firstN: {
            input: '$$ROOT',
            n: 10
          }
        }
      }
```

And I'm still getting an error with `MongoServerError: unknown group operator '$function'`

same with $function

also my mongodb database after running mongod is v6,0,1

Comment: You can use `allowDiskUse` option in case of memory issues.

Comment: Starting in MongoDB version 5.2, [`"$firstN"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/firstN/#mongodb-group-grp.-firstN) can be used to limit the number of items.  You can also specify your own javascript [`"$accumulator"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/accumulator/#mongodb-group-grp.-accumulator) (MongoDB version >= 4.4) to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @rickhg12hs It's what I want but I update my mongogodb with brew and I have the error

```MongoServerError: unknown group operator '$firstN'```
Not the my package.json use version 4.9 but it seem to be the latest

Comment: The error is coming from the server, so it must be running with a version before `"$firstN"` was introduced.  If you are a javascripter, you could write an `"$accumulator"` (assuming the server's version is 4.4 or greater).

Comment: @rickhg12hs strange, I used $function and I have the same error, but if I run mongod --version I got this: ```db version v6.0.1
Build Info: {
    "version": "6.0.1",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "system",
    "environment": {
        "distarch": "aarch64",
        "target_arch": "aarch64"
    }
}```

Comment: It's curious that `db version v6.0.1` but `MongoServerError: unknown group operator '$firstN'`.  Is the server "limited" in any way that could explain this?

Comment: @rickhg12hs it's a default config nothing has been modified I will update the query I used in the post to sho you

Comment: Here's a [`"$firstN"` example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6LiMkgM640D) and here's an [`"$accumulator"` example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sfWTAYMTxeH) (I'm a javascript novice so you should scrutinize the code).  Neither of these work for you?  mongoplayground.net uses the same version as yours.